# Get the ids and loop through post data

Tags: php, post

I post a form with the same input names+id at the end like that:

```
<input type="text" name="machine_1">
<input type="text" name="machine_11">
<input type="text" name="machine_23">
```

How loop through on each of them and get the id's in the loop?

I tried this way, but it will loop a lot without any data and what happens if there is more thank 100 id?

```
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){

$_POST["machine"]=$_POST["machine_".$i];

$id=$i;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `name="machine[]"` so that PHP will create the array automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` is an associate array, so you can loop through everything that's been posted like this:

```
//$k contains the id
//$v contains the submitted value
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    //test if id contains 'machine'
    if(stristr($k, 'machine')) {
        echo $v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a foreach loop, like so:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have:

```
$_POST["machine"]=$_POST["machine_".$i];
```

That's not the correct way. You want to store the value of `$_POST["machine_".$i]` to `$id` and then use it below.

This is probably what you need:

```
for($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
    $id = $_POST["machine_".$i]; 
    echo $id;
}
```

And if there are more than 100 elements, and you don't know the number of inputs, then you can use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop, as below:

```
$i = 1; // counter variable
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input) {
    if($key == "machine_".$i) {
        $id = $input; // or simply 'echo $input'
        echo $id;
    }
    $i++; // increment counter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST["machine"]=$_POST["machine_".$i];
```

here $_POST['machine'] represents noting..how can you assign a value to $_POST['machine']..you havent passed any element having name **machine** while submitting the form..so first of all you need to check it bro